# Insert a pane in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

In a VBox I already have two Grid Panes. Now I want to insert a new anchor pane between them. If I use the below code,

```
vBoxPane.getChildren().add(anchorPane);
```

it will insert anchor pane at last, but I want it inbetween the gridpanes. Is there any way?

Comment: @James_D I understand why you linked the answer about ArrayList as duplicated, but I don't think it directly answer the question of the OP.

Comment: How does it not? `getChildren()` returns a `List`; the question is asking how to place an item at a specific location in that list. The linked question asks how to insert an element at a specific index in a list. I honestly see no difference between these two questions: in both cases the OP is unaware of the overloaded `add(int index, E element)` method.

Comment: @James_D I think that the OP didn't know that the order of the elements in `getChildren()` determines the "visual order" of the shown nodes. It's like the answer to this question is A->B->C, but the linked answer is just B->C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a `VBox` as main container, the index of its children determine their vertical position.
So, if you want to place a child node in the middle, just insert it in the middle of the list returned by the `getChildren()` method.

Here is a complete runnable example:

```
public class Example extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    GridPane gridTop = new GridPane();
    GridPane gridBottom = new GridPane();
    VBox mainPanel = new VBox(gridTop, gridBottom);

    Label topLabel = new Label("Top");
    gridTop.add(topLabel, 0, 0);
    Button createAnchorPane = new Button("Create AnchorPane");
    gridBottom.add(createAnchorPane, 0, 0);

    createAnchorPane.setOnAction(event -> {
      Label centerLabel = new Label("Center");
      AnchorPane newPane = new AnchorPane();
      newPane.getChildren().add(centerLabel);
      // add the anchor pane in the middle
      mainPanel.getChildren().add(1, newPane);
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(mainPanel, 400, 400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```